# Lagrange interpolation on a Galois Field in time $O(n \log (n))$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, computational-complexity, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I have the values of a polynomial $p(x)$ defined on the Galois field mod $p$ (with $p$ prime) at the points zero to around two million. I need an algorithm to find the coefficients of the original polynomial $p(x)$ in time $O(n \log (n))$, as $O(n^2)$ is way too slow for this application. In Chapter 3 of Pan's *Structured Matrices and Polynomials* there is an algorithm, but it is stated that $|t_i| = 1$ for all $i$, which is not the case here. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Do you know the degree of your polynomial, and maybe the typical size of $p$ with respect to this degree?

Comment: @Aphelli the number of points is 1769611, so I guess the degree of the polynomial is that +1. Also p is 7514777789.